# Change color of glyph in ggplot-legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a layer of `geom_rect`. However, I am not able to change the color of the glyph in the legend. I am sure I have done this before, but I just can't remember or find how to.

The data I am using looks like this:

```
structure(list(name = 1:66, start = c(1988, 1982, 1981, 2008, 
2011, 1985, 1981, 1982, 2001, 2009, 2013, 2016, 2009, 2009, 2015, 
1981, 1997, 2006, 2009, 2008, 2009, 1998, 1981, 1991, 1995, 1981, 
2011, 2013, 1988, 1999, 1981, 1984, 1995, 1995, 2006, 1988, 1984, 
1996, 1981, 1992, 2003, 1988, 1994, 1981, 2013, 1981, 2010, 1981, 
2012, 1988, 1981, 1988, 2010, 2003, 1987, 1989, 1981, 2015, 1987, 
1995, 1982, 1988, 1987, 1984, 1999, 1990), end = c(2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2016, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)), row.names = c(NA, 
66L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I am doing something like this with ggplot:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = Inf,
    ymin = -Inf,
    ymax = Inf,
    fill = "a"
  ),
  # fill = "#f2f2f2",
  alpha = .01) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = start,
    xend = end,
    y = name,
    yend = name,
    col = name
  ),
  size = 1.2) +
  scale_color_scico(palette = "berlin",
                    name = "Years of Data") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("a" = "lightgrey"),
    labels = c("a" = ""),
    name  = "Years of interest"
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_colorbar(
      barwidth = unit(20, "lines"),
      title.position = "top",
      title.hjust = .5
    ),
    fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                        title.hjust = .5)
    
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
    legend.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman")
  )
```

Which gives this plot:

[image]

In this case the rectangle in the plot and in the legend combine. However, if I change the color of the rectangle in the plot to be red, I do not know how to change the color of the rectangle in the legend to be also red. I thought I could do something like this:

```
guides(
    color = guide_colorbar(
      barwidth = unit(20, "lines"),
      title.position = "top",
      title.hjust = .5
    ),
    fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                        title.hjust = .5,
                        override.aes = list(fill = "red")) # this one
```

But it does not work. So how could I make it work, that this code:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = Inf,
    ymin = -Inf,
    ymax = Inf,
    fill = "a"
  ),
  # fill = "#f2f2f2",
  alpha = .01) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = start,
    xend = end,
    y = name,
    yend = name,
    col = name
  ),
  size = 1.2) +
  scale_color_scico(palette = "berlin",
                    name = "Years of Data") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("a" = "red"), # using red here
    labels = c("a" = ""),
    name  = "Years of interest"
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_colorbar(
      barwidth = unit(20, "lines"),
      title.position = "top",
      title.hjust = .5
    ),
    fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                        title.hjust = .5)
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
    legend.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman")
  )
```

Would give me a red rectangle in the legend?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you set `alpha=0.01` for the rect, making the fill color nearly invisible. Hence, override the `alpha` aes too to get a colored glyph.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scico)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = Inf,
    ymin = -Inf,
    ymax = Inf,
    fill = "a"
  ),
  # fill = "#f2f2f2",
  alpha = .01
  ) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = start,
    xend = end,
    y = name,
    yend = name,
    col = name
  ),
  size = 1.2
  ) +
  scale_color_scico(
    palette = "berlin",
    name = "Years of Data"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("a" = "lightgrey"),
    labels = c("a" = ""),
    name = "Years of interest"
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_colorbar(
      barwidth = unit(20, "lines"),
      title.position = "top",
      title.hjust = .5
    ),
    fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                        title.hjust = .5,
                        override.aes = list(fill = "red", alpha = 1))) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
    legend.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman")
  )
```

[image]